# Mark as used android resources

Tags: android, android-resources

In our app we use some resources via their names.

```
getResources().getIdentifier(key, "string", getPackageName())
```

Is there a way to mark such resources as used?

Comment: _Is there a way to mark such resources as used?_ What is the purpose of this?

Comment: @B001 Lint checks, and "remove unused resources" option in android studio.

Comment: maybe storing/flagging in db or sharedstorage would be a solution?

Comment: @B001 the key of string is passed from server, also this string is localized at client side. At the moment the best way I see, is to create map of key/res_id, and lint will notice the usage of res. But maybe there is a solution to mark a res as used, to exclude it from lint checks.